# Parsing Json from a document body

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-parsing

I need to get the body of this page into an Object:

http://sob.ca.flyerservices.com/cached_banner_pages/AJAXProxy.aspx?bname=SOB&AJAXCall=GetPublicationData.aspx?view=PRODUCT&queryid=fc02e54c-079a-4623-8187-8b15d08da139&publicationid=1a9b1abe-0534-436a-83ab-8062e4801630&type=CATEGORY&languageid=1&bannerid=0f69e65d-a96e-4871-8f86-a5fe7dde96c0&bannername=SOB&customername=SOB&publicationtype=1

So far, i have (I'll spare you my 100 previous tries, this is the most promising):

```
//getting body
var json = document.body.innerHTML;
json = json.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," "); //get rid of html tags
```

The output in the console looks fine, but when I try to eval or parseJSON, it throws an Unexpected Token error... Any idea to get me started?

Thanks!

Edit: JSON might be complicated to get (see comments/answers), so what's my best course of action? 
My idea :

```
split by ({"productid": )
then split by (",")
```

I can't use comma alone as a separator, as the description field contains some...

Comment: Maybe your json source has some invalid characters. You can validate it here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I was just trying that, it complains about strings that contain `\'`

Comment: yep, was trying that too. After sorting out with replace('\\\'','\''), it complains some more...

Answer (score 0):

Even if you were to remove all the offending characters you still wouldn't be able to parse it as its invalid. See this line

```
"description": " or 8" Lemon Meringue Pie,
```

Comment: yep... so, a regex to replace \d\" with \d\'\' ? and fingers crossed ^^

Comment: Any other idea how to get the data? Basically, JSON or not, I need an object with all the products in there.

Comment: It should work for this particular case, but I have around 2000 pages like that to process, I'm trying to think of something more global.